# Does Angular / AngularDart allow components to display arbitrary child components?

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I am building a calendar component, and I would like to provide the following API to users:

```
<fancy-calendar>
    <my-custom-day [day]="day"></my-custom-day>
</fancy-calendar>
```

Where `fancy-calendar` is responsible for keeping track of the current month that the user selects. Internally, I would like to implement it using something like *ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let day of daysInMonth">
    <ng-content [day]="day"></ng-content>
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to work because `ng-content` can't send arbitrary values (in this case, the current day.)

Do I need to write a custom directive for this? How can I give users the ability to use their own component for days?

Comment: Can you give an example of why a user would want to use a custom day?

Comment: A custom day element is just so that users of the API can display dates however they like (colors, custom indicators, etc) for a given day, without worrying about what days need to be rendered at any given time.

for example, if the user selects a different month (e.g. Oct) the user may decide that they want to display an icon indicating there is an event on October 1st

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using dynamic component loading.
https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/7f6858bc48c1d2a454a4bc350077d67c277c6516/doc/faq/component-loading.md

I answered a similar question for TS in [Angular dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

The easiest way to use this with `*ngFor` is to build a helper component that you pass the type or factory to for the component you want it to create.

Another way would be using https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular/angular/NgTemplateOutlet-class
where the user passes content as template

```
<fancy-calendar>
    <ng-template> 
      <my-custom-day [day]="day"></my-custom-day>
    </ng-template>
</fancy-calendar>
```

and `fancy-calender` uses `NgTemplateOutlet` to render it.
With `*ngFor` https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular/angular/NgFor/ngForTemplate could be used as well to render the same template multiple times.